# How to enter 'NULL' into SSMS cell?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

In SQL Server Management Studio 2012, I was typing/pasting data into a table (via Edit Top 200 Rows).
Whenever I typed/pasted `NULL` in a cell, a `NULL` value was inserted. Apparently it thought I meant the `NULL` value instead of the `'NULL'` text. Which didn't work, as my column wasn't nullable...

Now how do I enter the `'NULL'` text into a cell?

If I wanted to insert the `NULL` value, I would have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>...

Comment: I guess a bigger question might be, why do you want a NULL text for something? Can't you just make the column nullable then use the NULL value? :)   And, you might have to do it the old school way, if you have a PK on the table, just do it like SET text = 'NULL' WHERE PK = ID.

Comment: @Joe – There can still be number of valid `'NULL'` uses. For example if the table represents a blacklist of SQL keywords.

Comment: The answer to my question, "How the heck do you enter NULL in a field again?" was answered in YOUR question...  Ctrl + Zero

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just enter `'NULL'` (with single quote mark) into cell, SSMS will trim leading and ending single quote mark and save it as string `'NULL'`.

Without single quote mark, SSMS will treat input as `NULL`.

Comment: Right! Even though the grid keeps showing the quotes, they are gone in the data.

Comment: It must be in all caps for SSMS to recognize it as NULL.   In an INT field, if I type null then it fails. (for reference I'm using v2012)

Answer (score 38):

Just press CTRL + 0
(why should the answer body longer than 30 cars?)

Comment: The question is how to enter the string expressed via the SQL literal `'NULL'` into a cell (i.e., the four character string formed by the characters `'N'`, `'U'`, `'L'`, and `'L'`). CTRL+0 sets the cell to `NULL` the conceptual non-value value. Please read the question more carefully.