# How to enter the text 'NULL' (with quotes) into SSMS cell?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table with some `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns in it. If I open SSMS and right-click on the table and say “Edit Top 200 Rows”, I can select that cell within a row and enter many different arbitrary values. What I want to do is update that cell to the value `'NULL'` which would be similar to running this SQL command:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.TableName SET ColumnName = '''NULL''' WHERE Id = 1;
```

However, when I write `'NULL'` into the editor’s cell, the effect is that the string `NULL` is written into the table. I.e., the editor behaves as if this command was executed instead of putting in the text I want:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.TableName SET ColumnName = 'NULL' WHERE Id = 1;
```

How do I use the editor to set the value of the cell to `'NULL'`? To clarify, I want the value of the cell to be a 6 character string. The characters in this string are, in order, single quote, capital N, capital U, capital L, capital L, and single quote. How do I achieve this using the “Edit Top 200 Rows” table editor’s Results Pane in SQL Server Management Studio?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/edit-rows-in-the-results-pane-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#to-edit-data-in-the-results-pane) doesn’t seem to mention this scenario. I have opened a [docs bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/4075).

*Note that this question is **not** the same as [How to enter 'NULL' into SSMS cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23734371)*

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I don’t follow. That would set the cell to the empty string. I want to set it to the string which is first a single quote, then the capital letter N, then the capital letter U, then the capital letter L, then the capital letter L, and finally another single quote.

Comment: I noticed that `'null'` (lower case) works, but indeed it's hard to find a solution for uppercase

Comment: I'm curious why you need this ;)  Is this just poor design or is there really a good reason?

Comment: @Julian this behavior confused us because we were trying to get the value of a cell to be `'NULL'`. We assumed that the value we inserted was `'NULL'` since that is what we typed and what the editor displayed. We needed this value because it was given to us by a vendor as the value to match on. Later, when checking with manually authored SQL commands, we discovered that the four character string `NULL` was being inserted instead. So, we now know how it works and were just curious if there even **was** a way to insert that value with the simple editor.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way! (Warning: need some steps!)

1. Go to Edit

   [image]
2. Change type to 'Insert Values'

   [image]
3. Show criteria pane

   [image]
4. Type `'''NULL'''` (so surrounded with triple quotes)

   [image]
5. Execute (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

proof:

[image]

I hope this is what you're looking for. It has some steps, but at least you don't need to write SQL.

Comment: I think this will be as close as I can hope for. I'll accept it for now ;-)

Comment: This method is quite removed from editing the Results pane, which is apparently what I hoped to find a solution for. If you want to edit an existing value (which is what I wanted), you can’t use the “Insert Values” type but have to use the “Update” type. Be careful to specify a Filter if you do this! Honestly, I think your answer would be better if you could just say “No, there isn’t a way. But here’s the closest way of getting the GUI to help you…”

Comment: Since I now know what the Results Pane is ;-) and I originally intended to ask how that could be done and this answer doesn’t use that, I will unaccept it as an answer for now (but if you update this to say “can’t be done with results pane”, it becomes acceptable to me ;-)—poke me if you do).

Comment: I'm confused. The original pane for editing is not the results pane? Also I don't think there is another option (and otherwise feel free to add an answer). I'm confused it's now unaccepted.

Comment: The [Results Pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/results-pane-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) is distinct from the [Criteria Pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/criteria-pane-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15). Yeah, I also don’t think there is another option. So I think the answer should simply be “it’s impossible” with the Results Pane.